# Why .getTime() return different values on different servers

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have piece of JavaScript (Node) code that it's been executed in two different servers and it looks like this:

```
//...
let myDate = new Date(timeValues.year, timeValues.month - 1, timeValues.day, timeValues.hour, 0, 0, 0);                        // line 1
console.log('Year: ', timeValues.year, 'Month: ', timeValues.month - 1, 'Day: ', timeValues.day, 'Hour: ', timeValues.hour);              // line 2
console.log('Date from App', myDate.getTime());               // line 3
// ...
```

I print out what comes in (line 2) and what comes out(line 3) the problem that I'm having is that I'm getting two different result from `.getTime()` and my question is why???

Comment: Timezones......

Comment: *What* different values you get? Have you confirmed that the servers' clocks are in the same time and in the same timezone?

Comment: Also, please make sure to clarify where ```timeValues``` comes from and what its value is.

Comment: Because JS is executed on client side it depends of the timezone. Although we call the same page on a server, but in different timezone, we will get different values :) if you want to serve the same time to everyone, you have to calculate the time on server side.

Answer (score 2):

The `.getTime` is based on the hardware running it, in the case of nodejs the hardware running it is the server, if your servers are located in different time zones you are getting different hours